# Monte Carlo simulation in R: For loop value return NA

Tags: r, for-loop

Monte Carlo simulation: The code is meant to simulate a demand of 260 and calculate the amount of 2nd shift required. However, I encounter NA in value after the 10th run. 
I am trying to achieve this: The first column start from 'B'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESk73.png)

```
        set.seed(1234)
        n = 260
        demand = runif(260, min = 80, max = 130)
        production_capacity = 100
        begining_inventory[] = 100
        post_inventory[] = 0
        counter = 0
        for(i in 1:n){
          if (i == 1){
            begining_inventory[i] = 100
            ending_inventory[i] = begining_inventory[i] + production_capacity - demand [i]
            ending_inventory[i]
            post_inventory[i] = ending_inventory[i]

          }
          else{
            post_inventory[i] = ending_inventory[i]
            begining_inventory[i] = post_inventory[i-1]
            ending_inventory[i] = begining_inventory[i] + production_capacity - demand [i]
          }
          if(ending_inventory[i] <= 50){
            counter = counter + 1
          }
         print(ending_inventory[i])
         P.first_shift = (1-counter/n)
         P.second_shift = 1-P.first_shift
        }
```

Comment: Output:
    [1] 78.22905
    [1] 85.84038
    [1] 87.66084
    [1] -24.41198
    [1] -34.38333
    [1] -28.49417
    [1] -2.289705
    [1] 36.06229
    [1] 106.3816
    Error in if (ending_inventory[i] <= 50) { : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    > post_inventory[i] = ending_inventory[i]
    > post_inventory[i]
    [1] NA

Comment: Please put additional information in your question (not in a comment), i.e. **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17930041

Comment: The question was clear. The value returns NA after the 10th loop.

Comment: So what is the correct way to initialize the variables?

Comment: Without the brackets, `begining_inventory = integer(desired_length)` is good. (Or `numeric(desired_length)`. Or `begining_inventory = rep(100, desired_length)` if you want it to all start at 100.) `begining_inventory[] = 100` will throw an error unless `begining_inventory` is already initialized.

Comment: I added a link to the image. I am trying to achieve how much additional 2nd shifts is required based on demand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
set.seed(1234)
n = 260
demand = runif(n, min = 80, max = 130)
production_capacity = 100
begining_inventory = 100

counter = 0
second_shift = rep(0,n)
ending_inventory = rep(0,n)

second_shift_production = rep(0,n)
post_second = rep(0,n)

for(i in 1:n){

  ending_inventory[i] = begining_inventory + production_capacity - demand[i]

  if(ending_inventory[i] < 50){
    print(ending_inventory[i])
    second_shift[i] = 1
    counter = counter + 1
  }else{
    second_shift[i] = 0 
  }
  second_shift_production[i] = second_shift[i]*100
  post_second[i] = second_shift_production[i] + ending_inventory[i]

  if(i > 1){
    begining_inventory = post_second[i-1]
  }

}
hist(ending_inventory)
abline(v = 50, col = "red")

P.first_shift = (1-counter/n)
P.second_shift = 1-P.first_shift

print(paste("Probabiity Only first shift = ", (1-counter/n)*100, "%", sep = " "))
print(paste("Probabiity second shift = ", 100-(1-counter/n)*100, "%", sep = " "))
```